# Ajax.ActionLink not posting

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

I have run in to a problem with an  `ajax.actionlink`

My code is:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteCategory", new { id = item.ID }, new AjaxOptions
               {
                   HttpMethod = "POST",
                   OnFailure = "function() { alert('fail'); }",
                   OnSuccess = "function() { alert('success'); }"
               })
```

and the controller is

```
 [HttpPost]
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult DeleteCategory(int id)
        {

            categoryBLL.DeleteCategory(id);
            return RedirectToAction("CreateCategory");

        }
```

But for some reason I can not get it to work, it doesn't get triggered...
It only redirects to `/DeleteCategory/Delete/{id}`

Instead of just posting to the controller, and carrying that out..

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you loading the client-side scripts correctly?

Comment: If your hitting the GET method rather than the post its because you have not included `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` (or have your scripts in the wrong order or have duplicates)

Answer (score 0):

first add the reference to the package **MicrosoftMvcAjax.Mvc5** and next add the js to your page:

[image: Nuget Package MicrosoftMvcAjax]

and the js references:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js"></script>
```

Also, exists some problem when you use @ajax.actionlink with HTTP Post, with get all its fine, get:

```
 @Ajax.ActionLink("Read", "Read", new { id = 1 }, new AjaxOptions
{
   HttpMethod = "Get",
   OnFailure = "function() { alert('fail'); }",
   OnSuccess = "function() { alert('success'); }"
})

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Read(int id)
{
    return RedirectToAction("CreateCategory");
}
```

But, for POST use the helper: `@Ajax.BeginForm()` or a library like jQuery.

Comment: In `@Ajax.ActionLink()` you typed `new { id = 1 }`. That's good enough for static value. Now what if I want to pass a value of a `textbox`. How am I supposed to do that? I have **strongly-typed** view.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Stephen Muecke.

the problem layed in my order of script..     `<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>`

And ofc. thanks for the help, to the rest of you.